# How to configure multiple Apache subdomains for .NET CORE 2.0 on UBUNTU?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, proxy, subdomain, asp.net-mvc

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15873940/3394380) and updated my config.

I have this reverse proxy configuration on Apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName a123.com
    ServerAlias www.a123.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/ [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/test2/" "http://localhost:48630"
    ProxyPassReverse "/test2/" "http://localhost:48630"
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:5000/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:5000/"
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/a123-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/a123-access.log common
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/a123.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/a123.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

How should this config be changed to access both www.a123.com and test2.a123.com subdomains?

I can only access www.a123.com or www.a123.com/test2/ now with this configuration?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write two VirtualHosts one for each domain and pass them to different locations.

Edit:
2 Virtual Host and no SSL

Edit: All subdomains must be allowed in DNS configuration as `*`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName a123.com
    ServerAlias www.a123.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:5000/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:5000/"
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/a123-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/a123-access.log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test2.a123.com
    ServerAlias www.test2.a123.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:48630/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:48630/"
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/test-a123-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/test-a123-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you give working example? Thanks.

Comment: I have added some code.

Comment: I put your code in 1 file. I can hit main website. When I try to hit subdomain I'll receive the error "server IP address could not be found."

Comment: Have you looked in the apache error log?

Comment: Error log shows some SSL errors. I changed DNS record to accept all requests as *.a123.com. When I try to hit test2.a123.com it redirects me to the main site a123.com

Comment: If you have only a SSL Cert for a123.com and no wildcard cert, then you can't use https://test2.a123.com. You need to have a valid cert for the subdomain.

Comment: I don't care about SSL errors.

Comment: I have answered a last try, all without SSL this time. If this does not work. I have no idea and recommend nginx.

Comment: I added 1 modification in the 2nd VirtualHost `ServerAlias www.test2.a123.com` to your answer and it starts working. I am accepting your answer. Congratulations ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

this is a virtualhost configuration. it will be applied for all the calls to your server using domain matching ServerName and ServerAlias directive. You can have more alias.

```
ServerAlias www.a123.com test2.a123.com
```

or if you want all subdomain:

```
ServerAlias *.a123.com
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it later and let you know if it works.

Comment: I tested, it works partially. Both main site and sub-domain point to the same place. How to rewrite ProxyPass or RewriteRule to point to different places for main and sub-domain sites?